# Front-End Form Submission in Shortcode

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, forms, wp-redirect

The plugin I am working on contains shortcodes with forms on them.  Upon form submission (POST), I do some database work, and then planned on redirecting to another page after the db work is complete.  When I attempt this, I get the "Headers Already Sent" warning.  Within the shortcode function, how do I call my redirect sooner than get_headers?  Do I need to use some separate callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hook an earlier action to check if the form was submitted. Something like:

```
function wpa_process_form(){
  if( isset( $_POST['my_form_data'] ) ){
      // process form and redirect
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_process_form' );
```

Comment: And this is another function that is tied to init, correct?  Not my same shortcode function?

Comment: correct, separate from your shortcode function.