# Use wp_redirect without filter in plugin file

Tags: wp-redirect

I created a little private plugin for me, which contains a form, that saves data to a database.

Every user should only have one dataset. If he already has one, he should only be able to edit his current one (similar to profile settings).

Thats no problem, works great. But I have one issue:
I want to redirect a user to his edit page, if he views the main plugin page (like site.com/submit/ -> site.com/submit/?id=das12d&edit=1)

So building this url is also no problem. But here is the real issue:
I tried using this:

```
wp-redirect( $url );
```

And

```
header('Location: '.$url);
```

But both causing a `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...` error

How can I solve it?

edit: Some sample code:

```
function login_data() {
    global $current_user;

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            show_submission($id);
        } else {
            } elseif(has_submission()) {
                $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'?id='.$get_submission_id();
                header('Location: '.$url);
            } else {
                show_form();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot redirect, or set any headers *after* sending output. Your plugin is sending output to the browser sometime before you call `wp_redirect`.

Comment: Please post more code. To answer this we need more context. Why don't you want to use a filter or action hook?

Comment: Hi I added the sample code. To be real: I dont know how to handle such thing with a filter/action.

Comment: I'm guessing you're sending output before calling `login_data`. Look at any calls to `login_form` and verify that no output has been sent yet.

Comment: How are you calling the login_data() function? Need more code

Comment: I call it via shortcode. Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/JpEbEqbv I know the if/else part in the main funciton is bad, but currently the most important thing is, that it works. Afterwards I will clean it up.

Comment: you can't do redirection inside a shortcode handler, output has already started. you need to check for redirection case and redirect earlier, see [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100924/front-end-form-submission-in-shortcode) or [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101498/redirect-function-inside-a-shortcode/).

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure what is really going on there, but one thing for sure your if statement is flawed, you should remove unneeded ELSE, should be like this:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            show_submission($id);
        } elseif(has_submission())  
             {
                $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'?id='.$get_submission_id();
                header('Location: '.$url);
            } else {
                show_form();
            }
        }
```

OR like this:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            show_submission($id);
        } else {
             if(has_submission()) {
                $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'?id='.$get_submission_id();
                header('Location: '.$url);
            } else {
                show_form();
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe this will fix the error

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree, that unneeded ELSE statements should be removed, but why should it solve the problem?

Comment: If there was a flaw, and show_submission was creating some output then it would cause that error

Comment: If this doesn't solve the problem, then you have something else in another function that is creating output before this function. I would use JS redirect if nothing worked.